# PHP search multiple zipcode

Tags: php, sql, search

I am trying to build an SQL search from input field "postcode" with multiple zipcode.

My input field is working like that: user add different zipcode (french),
the value of the input (name = postcode) is: value="35200, 53333, 23400"
the URL (post) after submit is: &postcode=35200%2C53333%2C23400

Now the query PHP part (working with only one postcode added):

```
$postcode = (!empty($array['postcode']) && !is_array($array['postcode']) AND $array['postcode'] != $language['value_postcode']) ? $bdd->quote($array['postcode']) : 0;
$condition .= (!empty($postcode)) ? " AND s.postcode = $postcode" : "";
```

This is working with ONLY ONE ZIPCODE ...

If I add an other zip code, the request is not working.
What to do to change the request working with multiple zipcode?

Comment: You have mentioned you are using post method, then how come your data is passed in querystring of URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Comma Delimted list as a search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286241/using-a-comma-delimted-list-as-a-search-query)

Comment: If you're using this to directly build a SQL query then it's highly vulnerable to SQL injection. You _must_ parameterise the query, for safety

Comment: @ADyson The SQL query is not directly built as i whrote ( for sql injection )

Comment: @Shingo this is not exactly what i want

Comment: `The SQL query is not directly built`... How so? `$condition .= (!empty($postcode)) ? " AND s.postcode = $postcode" : "";` looks like you're including the data from the input field directly into the SQL, to me. There certainly isn't any usage of parameters or placeholders there. Have a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: the data come exactly like the post URL , i mean 35200%2C53333%2C23400

Comment: `the data come exactly like the post URL`...try to be more specific. We don't even see how you are populating `$array` from the POST data. Normally PHP will url-decode it for you automatically.

Comment: Please clarify why that answer is not what you want, and what do you want?

Comment: the code is from a website i bought , i just tested it with an "online"  tester ( sql injection 
 ) and all is ok

Comment: @Rosebudwells can you please provide some more details or code that how data is getting populated in $array. and also provide what data is present in $array['postcode'] is it comma seperated or seperated by HEX(%2C)

Comment: The `postcode` column in your database contains what - single postcodes, presumably, one per record? Then you can of course not search with `AND s.postcode = ...`, and compare that with a comma-separated list of postcodes - `'123' = '123, 456'` simply is _not_ true. Your query either needs to use the `IN` operator then, or you need to "stretch" this into multiple OR-joined comparisons - `AND (s.postcode = '123' OR s.postcode = '456' OR ...)`

Comment: The postcode row in database  is like :  44000     without any character . the field input is fill by an autocompletion , it mean the value of the input is added by clicking on a postacode

Comment: the field input is like : value="44000, 75000, 85000"  (after multiple choice of the user 3 for this exemple )

Comment: the query was for ONLY one poscode , i want to change it for multiple

Comment: to be as clear as possible , the website contains ads  , in the database , each ads contains a title , a decription etc...and a postcode . the query mean i want to find ( user )  ads who contains this poscode or this postcode or this postcode etc...

Comment: actualy the website query is only for one postcode . i can find ads with postcode equal to XXXXXXX  , i want the query with multiple postcode . sorry for me english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already having comma separated values `value="35200, 53333, 23400"`

you can directly give a try with IN operator

```
$condition .= "AND s.postcode IN ($postcode)";
```

Comment: If you're passing in `$postcode` directly into the query, this could leave you vulnerable to SQL injection - I would recommend using an alternative solution using bound parameters instead

Comment: thanks you all and @ Zaid Malek , it is working great !

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already fetched the multiselect input as

```
value="44000, 75000, 85000"
```

So now, you only need to convert the string value **$postcode** into array as

```
$postcode_arr = explode(",", $postcode);
```

This way all your multiple values are accessible in $postcode_arr array for next requirement.

Reference link:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Otherwise, you have not added the question properly. So, I suggest you to add full code having database query generated from your form/data collector.
Then only, one can debug for any logical issue there may exist and depending that we can help you fix the issue.